# Close console when closing tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, console, exit

If have a tkinter gui for managing pypresence commands.
[Github](https://github.com/kaaaxcreators/advanced-discord-rpc/blob/master/discordrpc-gui.py)

### Problem

When I press the close button of the window the window closes, but the console stays open.
I tried other stuff, with py2exe but then sometimes the task stays, and you have do kill it manually.
But not to forget, i want that the console is there, but it should exit when i press exit in the tkinter window

Comment: I think its a problem with `py2exe`, maybe try `pyinstaller`

Comment: I don't know if you can do that....think about how your app is being run.  If it is running with a console, some sort of command ( like `python main.py` ) is run, and that contains your program and returns to the console afterwards.  Image if a helloworld program wanted to close the console it was run on.  Also, image if tkinter closes due to an error, it would send the error to the console and then just close it?  That would be a bit weird and hard to figure out what is going on.  I suppose technically, you could find the process with os and kill it...